# Network is unreachable if running script on webhosting

Tags: python, python-2.7

The next script runs fine on my mac. When I try to run it on my WebHosting (bluehost) I'm getting `socket.error: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable`. Any idea how can I fix it?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Required header that tells the browser how to render the text.
print "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n";

import imaplib
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login('user@gmail.com', 'password')
mail.list()
# Out: list of "folders" aka labels in gmail.
mail.select("inbox") # connect to inbox.
print mail.list()


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 6, in <module>
    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
  File "/home4/user/python27/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 1148, in __init__
    IMAP4.__init__(self, host, port)
  File "/home4/user/python27/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 163, in __init__
    self.open(host, port)
  File "/home4/user/python27/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 1159, in open
    self.sock = socket.create_connection((host, port))
  File "/home4/user/python27/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
socket.error: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
```

Their support isn't helpful at all.

Can it be port related or maybe SSL?

Comment: well what did you try? What did you get from pingong or running a traceroute?

Comment: try telnetting from your webhost to `imap.gmail.com` port 993 and see if you can connect that way.

Comment: I can't ping from the terminal `ping: icmp open socket: Operation not permitted` . I can't `traceroute -p 993 imap.gmail.com` Operation not permitted. The only thing I can do is `telnet imap.gmail.com 993` which gives me `Trying 74.125.141.108...
telnet: connect to address 74.125.141.108: Connection timed out telnet: connect to address 2607:f8b0:400e:c02::6c: Network is unreachable`. Their support:" Unfortunately this is not something we can assist you with, as it's not something we offer technical support for." Apparently They don't offer support if something on their end doesn't work.

Comment: [this](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/500) suggests they restrict outgoing connections. If you don't want to pay extra, you're probably out of luck.

Comment: @mata please write your comment as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On bluehosts [help pages](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/500) they mention that outgoing connnections are restricted, so ther problem isn't with your program. The only way of getting outbound connections to be allowed seems to pay for it.

Comment: In fact, after a lot of ping pong emails and chats with their support, even if I'll pay extra for Dedicated IP I could only access ports 1000 and up so even then 993 will be out of my reach. I already closed the account there.