# Send an email from Python script, without outgoing port access?

Tags: python, cron, smtp, bluehost

I've been beaten by Bluehost. I'm doing something similar [to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385162/network-is-unreachable-if-running-script-on-webhosting), except with `smtp.gmail.com:587` instead of IMAP.

Works beautifully from terminal (running locally), but [I wanted to automate it as a cron job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21804518/schedule-a-python-script-to-run-on-webserver). It failed silently tonight, so I tried via SSH, which is one I found the above problem - `socket.error: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable`.

I have a shared hosting plan, but [Bluehost say that even with a dedicated IP](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/405) they can only open ports >=1024.

Am I stuck, there is no way to do this? Any ideas for some kind of hacky work around where Python doesn't send an email, but signals something else to send an email..?

Bluehost can send an email when a cron job completes - any way to pass it a variable from Python, so that it can do the mailing for me?

Comment: This is really a question about what services bluehost provides, not about Python or anything else.

Comment: Also, it looks like they run a local `exim` server on your machine to transfer mail. Is there a reason you can't sending via the local server, and instead need to talk directly to gmail?

Comment: Well the question is "is there a Python/other work around because of this issue with the service". Sorry, I don't know what an exim server is. Gmail is the sent-from address.

Comment: There's no way Python can let you talk to a port you're not allowed to talk to. Or any other language. So you need to find some other way to send email. Whether that's using the mail server installed on the host, using a different third-party host who can listen on an IP above 1024, using some custom mail API that they provide, …

Comment: Or… doesn't gmail provide a web service API that you can use instead of SMTP?

Comment: I know it can't. "some other way" is *exactly* what I asked for: "Any ideas for some kind of hacky work around where Python doesn't send an email, but signals something else to send an email..?"

Comment: But that "something else" that it signals isn't going to be specific to Python, it's going to be something provided by Bluehost or a third-party provider that you have to go out and choose. If you find a good possibility and want to know how to talk to it from Python, that would make a good SO question. Asking someone else to pick a service for you (whether by shopping third-party solutions, or contacting Bluehost to see what they can provide you) is not a good SO question.

Comment: I have a Python variable to be emailed. I can't use outgoing ports. How to get that variable out to an eventual email was my question - I had no clue, asking for any suggestion not a personal shopper. HAL's answer is perfect, I will accept as soon as I get it to work.

Comment: See [the help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow". You may happen to get lucky and get an answer that works before your question gets closed, but relying on that isn't a good way to use the site.

Comment: I appreciate that, but you should realise that you're making assumptions about the answer in saying that. I didn't ask for a tool/library/program. @HAL's answer is poorly worded, but "use a different mail provider that supports sending via HTTP" is not a tool, etc. That's a technique for solving my problem. He further helpfully provides an example, but didn't need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluehost isn't allowing scripts access to other ports than 80 and 443 with a standard plan. Since your script tries to use port 587 it simply won't work. Check here for more details about Bluehosts policy: [help page on Bluehost](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/500)

One suggestion would be for you to use another email service that allows sending emails via another port, i.e. HTTP.  [mailgun](http://www.mailgun.com/) is one provider that offers this service.

Comment: I linked the relevant help page in my OP, I know they're not allowing it, I'm asking for another method. I'm not sending out a mailshot - the Python script does some calculation, and then sends an email containing a resulting variable.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure that you had read that the port was blocked. The suggestion was that your Python script could send emails via another service.

Comment: I looked at mailgun, but their SMTP server listens on 25, 587, and 465. So that's no good either. In fact, aren't those ports always the same for SMTP?

Comment: When sending out mails via mailgun, you can either use HTTP (port 80/443) or SMTP. In your case you would need to use HTTP.

Comment: Oh, well that's awesome, I'll look into it now.

Comment: I've accepted your answer, since I am confident I can make it work (waiting on propagation of update to CNAME records atm..) - though I cannot upvote unless you make an edit. I suggest this edit makes the answer clearer that I should seek a mail provider that allows HTTP instead/as well as SMTP - since this was not clear before comments. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the answer with your suggestions. Hope you get it to work!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the smtp server that BlueHost provides you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# email functions
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.MIMEImage import MIMEImage
import smtplib  
from email.Utils import COMMASPACE, formatdate

lines = ''
lines =  r'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">'
lines += r'<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">'
lines += r'<h1>Hi!'

yourSmtp = 'mail.yourDomain.com'
fromaddr = 'yourEmailName@yourDomain.com'  
password = 'yourPassword'
toaddrs  = ['whoEver@gmail.com']

msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = 'Hi'
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
# Record the MIME types of both parts - text/plain and text/html.
part1 = MIMEText("text", 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(lines, 'html')

# Attach parts into message container.
# According to RFC 2046, the last part of a multipart message, in this case
# the HTML message, is best and preferred.
msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)

server = smtplib.SMTP(yourSmtp,26)
server.set_debuglevel(0)
server.ehlo(yourSmtp)
server.starttls()
server.ehlo(yourSmtp)
server.login(fromaddr,password)
for toadd in toaddrs:
   msg['To'] = toadd
   server.sendmail(fromaddr, toadd, msg.as_string())  
server.quit()
```